# Facebook Album Access Token Expire every 2 hours

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing a photo album extension inside an umbraco installation. Basically it's just a usercontrol fetching photos from facebook.

I have supplied access_token with the following permissions:

- user_photos
- offline_access

However, the token seems to be expired after 2 hours. My question is how can I get my token to be valid all the time? Do I need more permissions?

thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?  I'd be interested in knowing if and how you've found a way to obtain a permanently valid token :)...

Comment: nope, haven't found yet.

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving a Facebook access token, an expiration time associated with the access token is also typically returned.  If this expiration time is exceeded, your application will need to obtain a new access token (which will also have a new expiration time associated with it).  Facebook has an article specifically regarding how to handle expired access tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/).

Comment: I don't think having to create an app in Facebook is the solution for this. This is a public website with no membership on it.

Comment: I don't see how that changes the need to refresh the access token after it expires -- even if it's a public website, you may still need to set up a Facebook app Id and provide the appropriate permissions to said Facebook app Id for the desired account to get the behavior you're after...

Comment: When the token expired and ask for permission, who's going to login to facebook and give permission?

Comment: The website is showing photo albums from many facebook users who have their albums public and using the graph api explorer to generate access token with permissions I mentioned. What do you think the better way to ask permission again for these users?

Comment: Well, you're never going to be able to completely get around expiration of the access token since Facebook deprecated the `offline_access` permission, but you might be able to extend it up to a day via a method described at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/